# How to create S3 Api storage account and storage using softlayer rest api?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to create a softlayer S3 api storage account using price id but I am getting error invalid price id.

```
{"error":"Invalid price Cloud Object Storage - S3 API (177723) provided on the order container.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid"}
```

also tried with 8177 with this getting following error,

```
{"error":"Invalid price MS SQL Server 2008 R2 - Enterprise - 2 processors (8177) provided on the order container.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Invalid"}
```

kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice that you post your code for the order that must be the issue:

For me this RESTful request is working fine:

```
POST https://$USERID:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder

payload:

{
    "parameters": [
          {
            "packageId": 206,
            "prices":              [{"id":177723}]
        }
        ]
}
```

you can get the prices for your account using this restful:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/206/getItemPrices
```

Maybe that is the issue the price for your account is different.

Regards

Comment: This works for me also. I am using same request but with different package,

place_order = "https://USER_ID:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder"

payload = '{"parameters" : [{"complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Hub", "quantity": 1, "packageId": 206, "prices": [{"id": 177723}]}]}'

as per this reference link https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis

Comment: so you were able to perform the oder right? your issue is gone

Comment: Yes Nelson, 

Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply, this works for me also.

I am using same request,

place_order = "https://USER_ID:API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder"

payload = '{"parameters" : [{"complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Hub", "quantity": 1, "packageId": 206, "prices": [{"id": 177723}]}]}'

as per this reference link https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis